# Python OS Error: A socket operation was attempted to an unreachable network

Tags: python, sockets, networking, ip-address

I have made a very simple python script which should connect using the public ip of a device. However when running I get this error: `OSError: [WinError 10051] A socket operation was attempted to an unreachable network`. I understand that this means my computer can't find a way to route to the ip, however I don't understand how to fix it.

Code:

```
import socket

ip = "some ip"

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind(("127.0.0.1", 5000))
s.connect((ip, 5000))
s.close()
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What is that IP, and is your computer hidden behind a proxy or a firewall?

Comment: @SergeBallesta Oops I forgot to remove it, and the normal windows firewall is active, but I've done other things with the socket and have managed to connect to websites with the same code (using url not ip). Could the firewall still be an issue?

Comment: You are doing a bind and a connect at the same time?

Comment: @KlausD. Yes I removed it and got a different situation now (I only added it because I saw it in someone elses answer). I edited the question with the new issue

Comment: @KlausD. My fault, after removing the bind it worked. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

Very simple fix, I just had to remove the bind and change the connect port to 80.
Working code:

````
import socket

ip = "some ip"

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
print("Finding connection to target")
s.connect((ip, 80))
print("Connected to " + ip)
s.close()```
````